# Cannot open new frames with undo-tree installed

Tags: emacs, undo

I use `undo-tree` 0.6.5 (from Elpa), and it works quite well most of the time. However, if I have not yet called `C-x-u` on a buffer, then *from this buffer* I can't open a new frame. If I do `C-x-5-2`, Emacs opens the `*Backtrace* buffer with this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument undo-tree nil)
  signal(wrong-type-argument (undo-tree nil))
  undo-tree-current(nil)
  (undo-tree-node-previous (undo-tree-current buffer-undo-tree))
  (and undo-tree-mode (not buffer-read-only) (not (eq t buffer-undo-list)) (undo-tree-node-previous (undo-tree-current buffer-undo-tree)))
  x-create-frame(((visibility) (vertical-scroll-bars . left) (reverse . t)))
  x-create-frame-with-faces(((vertical-scroll-bars . left) (reverse . t)))
  #f(compiled-function (params) #<bytecode 0x1fdd4b1bc7bf>)(((vertical-scroll-bars . left) (reverse . t)))
  apply(#f(compiled-function (params) #<bytecode 0x1fdd4b1bc7bf>) ((vertical-scroll-bars . left) (reverse . t)))
  frame-creation-function(((vertical-scroll-bars . left) (reverse . t)))
  make-frame()
  make-frame-command()
  funcall-interactively(make-frame-command)
  call-interactively(make-frame-command nil nil)
  command-execute(make-frame-command)
```

Then, I do `C-x-u` so the `undo-tree` buffer related to that buffer is created, and from then on I can create other frames.

Is there a workaround for this?

**edit:** it also prevents the use of menus. When I try to click on any menu item, the same message shows up.

**edit:** opening Emacs with this minimalistic startup file gives the same error:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
             "~/.emacs.d/elpa/undo-tree-0.6.5")

(require 'undo-tree)
(global-undo-tree-mode)
(setq debug-on-error t)
```

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew indeed, with `-Q` and loading undo-tree only, it doesn't happen. Ok, will bisect the init file...

Comment: @Drew i included a minimum (non-)working example now

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like it might be a bug. Please consider reporting it to the `undo-tree` maintainer or perhaps to Emacs dev (using `M-x report-emacs-bug`).

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior having just started using undo-tree.  I typically start a daemon and later launch a client to bring up the first frame and do the frame/gui init then.   I'll be interested to know if it is a bug or how else to work around it.

Comment: @RobDavenport See my answer to my own question... There is a new version of undo-tree, not released on ELPA.

Comment: Thanks @Jay - I just discovered that too and was going to report it.  Hmm - I don't see your answer to your question, must be looking in the wrong place.
I found in the author's undo-tree git repo commit 43663f6c which adds line 1245 and 1254 "(not (eq nil buffer-undo-tree))" - sounds like it could help.  That commit is listed in the log as being in the 0.6.5 release, but clearly not in the "0.6.5" package I pulled from ELPA.    Trying with the "0.6.6+" version from the repo now.  So far no problems.

Comment: Duh - had to refresh the page...

Comment: Hope the 0.6.6 version gets pushed to ELPA - hint, hint dr.qubit... :)

Comment: @RobDavenport it's been a while since 0.6.6 got ready, and it did not get into ELPA yet, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got it working. I was using the ELPA version of `undo-tree`, which is version 0.6.5. So a couple of days ago I noticed that the developer has a new version in his git repository, 0.6.6. I installed it locally and the problem was gone!

First, get a copy of the git repository:

```
$ cd ~/.emacs.d
$ git clone http://www.dr-qubit.org/git/undo-tree.git
```

Then add this to your Emacs config:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/undo-tree/undo-tree.el")
(require 'undo-tree)
(global-undo-tree-mode)
```